# Ajax обновление

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

В общем имеется страница с блоками в каждом фото, описание и кнопка с таймером. Данные загружаются из базы по циклу while. Как мне сделать обновление кнопки с таймером каждую секунду в каждом блоке? У меня только получилось сделать обновление всей страницы, то есть данные берутся из файла и все блоки загружаются на странице.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятна организация вашего кода, но например для каждой кнопки (jQuery):

```
  $( "button" ).each( function(index, element)
  {

      setInterval(function() {
          // get-запрос к серверу
          $.get(
             <url запроса>, 
             <параметры>, 
             function(data) //Функция обратного вызова при получении результата от сервера
             {
                 // data - данные, возвращаемые сервером. Например в виде json
                 // делаем что-то с вашей кнопкой element, который "button"
             }
          });
      }, <интервал запроса>);

  }
```

Comment: Все данные берутся из базы циклом while то есть нужно что бы в первом блоке обновилась информация для первого блока во втором для второго и т.д. Что бы ajax обрабатывал каждый блок отдельно.

Comment: Тогда при помощи команды $("<нужный блок>") находите нужный блок и присваиваете ему необходимые значения

Comment: То есть нужно будет каждому блоку присвоить уникальный id и затем искать через jquery? Правильно понял?

Comment: Можно и так, а можно и через $("div").each() как вот тут http://api.jquery.com/each/, или не div, а что там у вас, li например, или другие валидые значения для метода $